# How can Devhelp be installed on Windows, with GTK+ stable documentation?

Tags: windows-10, documentation, gtk3, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I searched with Google for Windows binaries of [Devhelp](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp) but I did not find something useful. I use MSYS2 and in the MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit terminal I executed `pacman -Q devhelp` and `pacman -S devhelp`, but the package could not be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Google I found [this official list of MSYS2 pacman packages](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/i686/). Here I pressed in the browser the key combination <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> and typed `devhelp`. I found these resulting file names:

- `mingw-w64-i686-devhelp-3.8.2-2-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig` - 2016-10-20
- `mingw-w64-i686-devhelp-3.8.2-2-any.pkg.tar.xz` - 2016-10-20

So I executed: `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-devhelp`. Then I was able to execute `devhelp` from the terminal and to execute the file `C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\devhelp.exe` and make a shortcut to it. I did not have to install another package to have the GTK+ 3 documentation inside Devhelp. It was there from the start.

If I knew from the start how to use `pacman`, I would have solved this problem faster. For `pacman` help I installed `man-db` using `pacman -S man-db` and then executed `man pacman`. From the shown information I discovered this method of searching for an available package:

```
hope@hope-PC MINGW32 ~
$ pacman -Ss devhelp
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-devhelp 3.8.2-2
    Remote desktop client for the GNOME Desktop (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-devhelp 3.8.2-2
    Remote desktop client for the GNOME Desktop (mingw-w64)
```